# Subtract percentage of scrollTop from div's width on scroll with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, scrolltop

I'm attempting to adjust a div's width on scroll with jQuery, the idea is to have a div's width be reduced by a fraction of the scrolltop value, every time you scroll.

For example say I have a div with a width of 100px, if I scrolled down 20px from the top of the page, and the function declared to subtract 1/2 of the current scrolltop value, the div's width would become 90px.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x = 0.5; //define whatever rate you want.

 $(document).scroll(function() { //whenever a scroll is happening -
    $('#divId').width($('#divId').width()-$(document).scrollTop()*x);

    //capture your div's width and set it to a new width that equals
    //to the subtraction between it's original width and the current 
    //scrolltop (multiplied by half, as you defined). so in your case 
    //if div's width is 100px and scrolltop is 20px, divId's new width
    //will be 100px - (20px * 0.5) = 90px  
});
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I'm looking for but my div's width is always 0 with this in place, I'm going to make a fiddle to test.

Comment: Adding an explanation to what the code does (and how it solves the issue) makes it better for the community as a whole (not just the individual answer)

Comment: you're right! im still quite new to stackoverflow. edited my answer! hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the code which reduces the width by 10% of height scrolled https://jsfiddle.net/x3o439kt/

code :

```
$('#myDiv').on('scroll',function(e){
var w= $('#myDiv').scrollTop()*10/100;
$('#myDiv').width($('#myDiv').width()-w);
});
```

You can replace 10 by any percentage you want.
if you want the scrolling to be done for the entire document, just replace #mydiv with document like so https://jsfiddle.net/x3o439kt/3/